# Is There A Faster Way To Pull Production Data From Heroku Than Taps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I often need to clone production data to investigate bugs. Even with a trivial database size heroku db:pull (taps) takes 5+ minutes and seems to have a high chance of failing. **Is there an alternative method to pull the database?**

Libraries for alternative processes / articles would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out [pgbackups](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups). It has replaced the Heroku bundle command and will give you a the postgres equivalent of mysqldump. This is far more civilized than Taps for large datasets.

```
heroku pgbackups:capture
```

Will create a dumpfile and store it. To download the dumpfile you need the url which you get with

```
heroku pgbackups:url b001 (or whatever the id number of the backup is)
```

That will return an url from which you can download your dump. You can paste it into Firefox if you want or use curl/wget like they suggest. The use pg_restore to load the dump file into your database as they say in the docs:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U test_user -d myapp_development /home/mike/Downloads/b001.dump
```

pg_restore: connecting to database for restore

Comment: I'm already aware of pg backups but I don't know how you can use it to integrate a local pg database. Would you be able to expand on your answer?

Comment: I've added some details to my answer Jack. Give it a try and let me know if it works for you. I am going to look at that UTF8 thing and I'll update when I get it figured out.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll check that out today

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I'm new to heroku and postgres and wasn't sure how this was accomplished

Answer (score 12):

I created a shell script that automates this process (based on Mike Williamson's answer).

https://gist.github.com/921535

```
#!/bin/bash

# Best use case is to create a file "update_local_db.sh" in your project folder and then     
# call the command with bash update_local_db

# Follow me: @jackkinsella

function LastBackupName () { 
  heroku pgbackups | tail -n 1 | cut -d"|" -f 1
}

# This part assumes you have a low limit on no. of backups allowed
old_backup=$(LastBackupName)
heroku pgbackups:destroy $old_backup 

heroku pgbackups:capture 
new_backup=$(LastBackupName)
curl $(heroku pgbackups:url $new_backup) > temporary_backup.dump
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USER -d REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_DB_NAME temporary_backup.dump 
rm -f temporary_backup.dump
```

Comment: Great script, so much faster than db:pull and a solution to the problem of not finding taps. I'm getting the output of heroku pgbackups separated by spaces rather than "|" so need to use 'cut -d" " . I'd also prefer to destroy my old Heroku backup after I save a new one, rather than before. Since Heroku now has a liberal policy on saving backups, we can skip the deletion entirely.

Comment: I had to change the delimiter to a space. ie. 
  heroku pgbackups | tail -n 1 | cut -d" " -f 1

Answer (score 3):

Mike's correct - [PGBackups](http://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups) is the way to do this. When you create a backup with PGBackups, you get access to a standard pg_dump file. [Here's](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#exporting_via_a_backup) the relevant section of the Dev Center PGBackups article.

Answer (score 1):

This post is quite old right now.

The newest and easiest method right now is using Heroku's [pg:pull/pg:push](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull)

Comment: True. but the point is that `pg:pull` is much slower than downloading a DB dump and importing.

Answer (score 0):

An update to [Jack's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5675869/3205492) script, with [Heroku's recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) as of Jan 2015.

The first part is due to running on different computers, hence my Postgres dbs has different names.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run the following command: bash update_local_db.sh

# Getting computer name, which is the same as username in Postgres db
echo "Please enter name of Computer"
read input_variable
echo "You entered: $input_variable"

# Make a backup on Heroku
heroku pgbackups:capture --app APP_NAME
echo "== Created a new backup =="

# Download the backup and name it latest.dump
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url --app APP_NAME`
echo "== Downloaded the backup =="

# Restore local db with latest.dump
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U $input_variable -d my_db_name latest.dump
echo "== Replaced db with downloaded =="

# Delete downloaded db latest.dump
rm -f latest.dump
echo "== Deleted downloaded db =="
echo "== Done! :) =="
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I wrote that utilizes `pg:pull`, as mentioned by Lomefin, to pull down a db from Heroku and replace a local one with it:

```
#!/bin/bash

export MAIN_DB=NAME_OF_LOCAL_DB
export TMP_DB=NAME_OF_TEMPORARY_DB

function delete_db () {
    psql -d ${1} -c "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '$1'
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();" || true

    dropdb ${1} || true
}

delete_db ${TMP_DB}

heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL ${TMP_DB} || exit 1

delete_db ${MAIN_DB}

psql -c "ALTER DATABASE $TMP_DB RENAME TO $MAIN_DB;"
```

Since `pg:pull` clones to a new database, your work will not be interrupted (only once it renames the db, which takes a fraction of a second). The script can, of course, be easily customized to your liking.