# Faster way to pull data from Heroku not using Taps... part II

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, taps

I've been trying to use the solution described in this post:
[Is There A Faster Way To Pull Production Data From Heroku Than Taps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649868/is-there-a-faster-way-to-pull-production-data-from-heroku-than-taps/)

But I use Mysql locally, other than PostgreSQL.
Is there a way to use that solution but still using Mysql for development?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the inconsistencies between Mysql and Postgres (I've just experienced pain on a project), I would advise installing Postgres locally. Then you could write a simple worker script using a rake task / delayed job that dumps the current database state to Amazon S3. Running this nightly gives you 24hr backups, which might be all you need in many scenarios. Or you could run it on demand so you can download it.

Answer (score 1):

You always want to develop against the production DB as close as possible - I run both mySQL and Postgres locally depending on my application needs and target deployment platform. I've seen countless problems with people not doing this - it'll save time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are more comfortable with MySql (because you should install Postgres locally if you are going to use Postgres for production) then you should consider using one of the MySql add-ons heroku offers:

https://addons.heroku.com/

ClearDB MySQL Database or Xeround Cloud Database

both offer ways to backup your db locally.