# heroku db:pull = Taps Server Error: undefined method `database_url' for #<DbSession

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, taps

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.2.8)
heroku (2.33.0)
heroku-api (0.3.6)
taps (0.3.24)
```

Despite having worked for months up until this morning, running `heroku db:pull` now starts to pull in the schema, but eventually results in:

```
Schema:         23% |=========                                 | ETA:  00:02:17
Schema:         23% |=========                                 | ETA:  00:02:15
Schema:         24% |==========                                | ETA:  00:02:13
Schema:         25% |==========                                | ETA:  00:02:11
Schema:         26% |==========                                | ETA:  00:02:09
Schema:         26% |==========                                | ETA:  00:02:08
Schema:         27% |===========                               | ETA:  00:02:06
Schema:         28% |===========                               | ETA:  00:02:04
Schema:         29% |============                              | ETA:  00:02:02
Schema:         29% |============                              | ETA:  00:02:00
Schema:         30% |============                              | ETA:  00:02:01
Saving session to pull_201211010614.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: undefined method `database_url' for #<DbSession:0x00000002710b18>
["/app/lib/taps/server.rb:149:in `block in <class:Server>'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'", "/home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'", "/home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:15:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `block in call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'", "/home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:77:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `block in pre_process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'"]
```

Anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this worked on the third or fourth try for me today. The thing is, the db:pull process is so absurdly slow that you should look for another option. Check out this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5675869/195530

Comment: Sure enough, I just tried two more times and on the second it succeeded.  Sadly, this does little to pinpoint the problem.  But thanks for the link, great solution.